# Infinitive or gerund complement clause

Tags: grammar

Which is more grammatically correct:

"I like to speak Japanese."

or

"I like speaking Japanese."

Also, do they mean the same thing? Why is one better than the other, if they differ?

Comment: They are both grammatical. They both mean the same thing. The verb _like_ can take either an infinitive complement clause (_to speak Japanese_) or a gerund complement clause (_speaking Japanese_). Every verb has its own rules about what kinds of complement clause they can take. That's all.

Comment: But doesn't "I like speaking Japanese" imply "I am speaking Japanese"? I don't mean directly but indirectly. Meaning that I am speaking Japanese in the first place.

Comment: *Both* imply you speak Japanese. If you *don't* speak Japanese you should say "I *would* like to speak Japanese" (meaning you would like to learn it) or "I *would* like speaking Japanese" (meaning you would enjoy doing so if you learned it).

Comment: @StoneyB~ I think they are referring to the notion (often found on grammar blogs) that "I like -ing" should be used when -ing is a regular activity, but "I like to -" should be used when don't get the opportunity to '-' as often as you would like. For example "I like swimming; I do it every morning" -v- "I like to swim but I am too busy to find the time"

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical, but sometimes the *to*-infinitive describes a possible action (particularly when the preceding clause includes *would*), and the *-ing* form describes the actual performance of the action. Whether that distinction is relevant in this case could be determined only by knowing more about the context.